# React Native: Initializing the app json playstore url prior to uploading the app to play store

Tags: react-native, google-play, app-store, expo

I am uploading my app for the first time.
It is written in react native that uses Expo managed flow.
I need to initialize the playstore url in the app.json file so for example, the expo-store-review will work and users will be able to rate my app.

But how can I initialize it before I am uploading and publishing my app?
Is there any convention for that?
I can do it after publishing my app but them I will need to wait another few days for Google to review and approve my app...

Same question for appStoreUrl in iOS.

Thanks...